# How to make Tableau run query for combined multiple selections in quick filter, example attached

Tags: filter, tableau-api

It is hard to describe my question in the subject line. Here is an example.

[image]

I want Tableau to run query to show only Account ID that has both 2 products i selected in Product A quick filter.In this example only the second Account ID should qualify . Is this possible?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: I've got a firm answer from Tableau that this can not be done in tableau at this point. And they will send a feature request to consider adding it as a new feature.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, good question. It is not possible in the way you want (at least I can't think of a way to do that), with quick filters.

I can solve your specific problem (filtering customers that have at least 2 specific products in their history), but expanding for variable n products can be really troublesome.

So first thing, create 2 parameters. Product1 and Product2. Each is a string, and you can get a list from the [Product A] field. You will use this 2 parameters to specify the 2 products you want.

Now create a calculated field, [Product flag]:

```
IF [Product A] = [Product1] OR [Product A] = [Product2]
THEN 1
END
```

Now drag [Account ID] to the filters shelf. Open the filter options and go to condition. Now select By field, [Product flag], Sum, = 2

That will work if there are not duplicated [Product A] under the same [Account ID]. If that can happen, you need a little bit more sophisticated approach. [Product Flag] becomes:

```
IF [Product A] = [Product1]
THEN 1
ELSEIF [Product A] = [Product2]
THEN 2
END
```

And the condition should be Count (Distinct) = 2

In both cases it will keep only the Account IDs that have both the products you selected under them. They can have other products under them.

EDIT: For the N product problem, I believe you're going to use a solution outside Tableau. One possibility is to use the JS API, so you can select the products you need in a JS interface, and pass a parameter to Tableau.

In JS you could have a list you could select as many items you want, and a script to pass a parameter to Tableau based on the selection. Could be something like: product1,product2,product3...

Then you could use CONTAINS() to see if that product is in that list (and raise a flag), and make a count of ',' to see how many products were selected.

Unfortunately I have very limited knowledge on JS API, but I strong encourage you to take a look

Comment: Thank you! Yes your approach should work for this specific example, but unfortunately i will expand for N products and that N can be as big as 30...I will keep searching for solutions and if i discovered anything, i will come back here and post it. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Put an addition. I believe you cannot solve the problem with Tableau alone. But you may be able to use JS API to solve it. TAke a look

Comment: Awww, too bad that i don't know Java at all :( Thanks though! I've contacted Tableau tech support and waiting for a solution now. Will come update if they come up with something creative.

Comment: Javascript has nothing to do with Java. But I guess you don't know neither :). Keep us posted if something good appears

Answer (score 1):

Really interesting question. It's surprisingly trickier to list the accounts that reference **every** product in a list than it is to list the accounts that reference **any** product in a list.

If you are willing to start with a less convenient user interface (suitable for ad-hoc analysis but not published dashboards) then try the following:

Create a filter based on Account Id, select **Use all** on the General tab, and **By formula** on the Condition tab. Enter the formula
`Count(if [Product A] = "Business Office Consolidation" then 1 end) > 0 and Count(if [Product A] = "Cabled Barcode Scanner" then 1 end) > 0`

This will only filter to only include Account IDs that reference both products. You can extend this to a list of any number of required products. For relational data sources, it is implemented using a HAVING clause.

Of course, it can be tedious to revise this formula by hand, but it is one way to accomplish your analysis goal, and it can be instructive to understand how filter conditions work. Similar formulas are useful for many conditions.

You can create one or more dynamic sets using the same approach and then use them in calculated fields, any shelf in Tableau and combine them to create new sets. You can also move the formula to a calculated field for convenience.

Note, the 1 in the formula is not significant, any non-null value would work. Since there is no else clause, the formula evaluates to null for rows that fail the if test. And the Count() function just counts the number of rows that have non-null values for the expression.

To come up with an approach that lets you easily select products from a list without editing a formula, will probably take some combination of more advanced features. I don't have an answer for you right now, but the features that are worth learning about that may or may not be part of the solution include filter actions, context filters, top filters, count distinct, custom SQL, computed sets, table calculations, LOD expressions and the Javascript API. This would also be a good questions to pose, with an example workbook, on the Tableau online forums at http://www.tableau.com under the Support menu.